# MySQL connection via SSH tunnel

Tags: terminal, ssh, vpn, big-sur, mysql

I've been trying to set up a SSH tunnel with VPN on my macbook with Big Sur 11.2, but it doesn't seem to work.

On my linux machine, I can simply turn on the VPN and make a SSH-tunnel. Then I can just connect to the MySQL server via port `3307`. If I do the same on my macbook, the SSH tunnel does connect, but I can't connect to the MySQL server on the given port.

My exact steps are:

1. Turn on VPN so I can access the server via SSH.
2. Run `ssh -g -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@ip_address` in the terminal.
3. Run `mysql -u user -p -h [IP] -P 3307` to connect to the MySQL SSH tunnel.
4. Error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on '[IP]'`.

Above works fine on my linux system, but not on my mac. I am able to SSH to the server with the command, but the tunnel itself is not working.

Is there some reason this is happening, and how should I proceed?

Comment: So it looks like you can connect locally, but not remotely. I’d suspect that your user is not authorized to connect to MySQL from a remote machine. Please add more info to your question: what’s the error message and which access rights does the user have that you use to connect?

Comment: @not2savvy I am able to connect via SSH to the remote server and run MySQL scripts there. I updated my question.

Comment: Not too sure, but when you create the SSH tunnel between your macbook and the server, shouldn't you use the server IP address in the `ssh` command? And shouldn't you use the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) in the `mysql` command and not the server IP? Or maybe I'm confused...

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke that was it! I thought I had to connect to the VPN's IP, but that was wrong. Can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have swapped the local address and the remote server address around. For example [this site](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403884/tunnel-local-mysql-server-through-ssh) explains it should be:

1. Create an SSH tunnel from you client to the server:
   `ssh -g -L 3307:server-ip:3306 user@server-ip`
   Now port 3306 of the server is exposed on 3307 on the client.
2. On the client connect MySQL to the 3307 port:
   `mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.01 -P 3307`
   Note that you have to connect to the local loopback address `127.0.0.1` as the SSH tunnel already forwarded the connection to the client.